# Password dialogs block keybindings

Tags: gpg, xmonad, evolution

I am using XMonad 0.11, but this might be unrelated.
I am using `evolution` 3.12.2 and this *is* related, but the problem might be more general.
After research, it appears that the window in question is `pinentry` and comes from GPG2.

Some password dialogs prevent me from using my keybindings. Usually this is caused by `evolution`.

The following happens:

- I am not able to switch workspaces or change the focus with the keyboard; changing focus with the mouse still works.
- I cannot move the window using keybindings alone (i.e, `META-SHIFT-1`), but the combination `META-MOUSE1` to move works.
- The non window manager keys don't all work, either: `ESCAPE` is ignored but `RETURN` works. Insert from clipboard does not work either (although this may be intentional for a password field).
- In fact, any keyboard input is redirected to the password fields and the meta combinations appear as normal letters (e.g, if I try `META-SHIFT-1` to move the window an * appears in the password field, most likely masking a 1).
- As soon as the dialog is closed, using mouse or enter, the system behaves normally again.

I would like to fix this as this is very annoying when a password window pops up unexpectedly.

Comment: This seems to be the intentional behavior: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1-gnome/+bug/630226 Is there a way to disable this feature?